# How to print a given array in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
{
    MNC:
    [
        {
            instanceId: 'i-0c025b0755f5e3e5d6',
            systemId: 'NWD',
            instanceState: 'running',
            tags: [Array],
            env_type: 'DB_CI_APP'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to print the above array in JSON format as

```
{
    "key": "MNC",
    "value":
    [
        {
            "instanceId": "i-0c025b0755f5e3e5d6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2); // spacing level = 2

Comment: I really think you could have researched this _very_ easily yourself. There will be many previous questions and other posts online which would explain it.

Comment: That output does not look like valid JSON after all

Comment: Bharata, Thanks for your reply... i found it useful

Comment: @ShanmugaPerumal, you are welcome! But please do not forget @ symbol before my name. Because without it I do not get the notification about your feedback.

Comment: @Bharata okay sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it on this way:

```js
var obj =
{
    MNC:
    [
        {
            instanceId: 'i-0c025b0755f5e3e5d6',
            systemId: 'NWD',
            instanceState: 'running',
            tags: [Array],
            env_type: 'DB_CI_APP'
        }
    ]
};

var newObj = {};

for(var key in obj)
{
    newObj['key'] = key;
    break;
}

newObj.value = obj[newObj['key']];

delete newObj.value[0].systemId;
delete newObj.value[0].instanceState;
delete newObj.value[0].tags;
delete newObj.value[0].env_type;

var yourJSONstr = JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 4);

console.log(yourJSONstr);
```

Or you could do this on following way too:

```js
var obj =
{
    MNC:
    [
        {
            instanceId: 'i-0c025b0755f5e3e5d6',
            systemId: 'NWD',
            instanceState: 'running',
            tags: [Array],
            env_type: 'DB_CI_APP'
        }
    ]
};

var newObj = {key: 'MNC', value: obj.MNC};

delete newObj.value[0].systemId;
delete newObj.value[0].instanceState;
delete newObj.value[0].tags;
delete newObj.value[0].env_type;

var yourJSONstr = JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 4);

console.log(yourJSONstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can use `JSON.stringify` to convert an array or values into a JSON formatted string.

```js
var x = [{'a': 'b'}];
var b = JSON.stringify(x);
var c = b.substring(1, b.length - 1);
JSON.parse(c);
console.log(c);
```